# Android hard-reset on a chinese phone

Tags: android

I'm attempting to make a cheap phone usable for someone.
It's full of apps, and every 5 seconds there is a popup memory is full.
I thought the easiest way would be to just hard-reset it. From the android settings menu, when i tap factory reset, nothing happens. So I went into download mode by holding down volume down and power. The menu i see now is Chinese so can't make anything out of it.[image: chinese download mode]
tried using google translate with camera to no avail.
Any chance somebody could walk me through to change the language, or hard-reset?

Comment: Factory reset should uninstall apps except default apps. What is the operating system?

Comment: it's android device, the answer below worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below image and select option according to that.[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2unSxN5TLsA

no memory errors anymore

Answer (score 0):

use google lens to figure out the translation of what the buttons mean then press the power button on the figure u desire tip to scroll you have to use volume down to select you have to use power button hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).